# How to prove that a real matrix with a non-real eigenvalue is not diagonalizable over the reals?

Tags: linear-algebra

For example, $\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{array} \right)$ has eigenvalues $1\pm i$ over $\mathbb{C}$ but no eigenvalue over $\mathbb{R}$. It is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$ but not over $\mathbb{R}$. But I wonder how to prove the general case. It seems that the argument of algebraic multiplicity equal geometric multiplicity for each eigenvalue does not quite work here...because the matrix has no eigenvalue if considered to be over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If it where diagonalizable (say the matrix is similar to $D$, with $D$ diagonal) then the numbers appearing on the diagonal of $D$ would be eigenvalues for your original matrix.

Comment: The relation $A = PDP^{-1}$, where $D$ is diagonal, means exactly that the eigenvalues of $A$ are the diagonal elements of $D$, and the corresponding eigenvectors are the columns of $P$.

Comment: The geometric multiplicity of $1+i$ for that matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ is zero, since only the zero vector is in its eigenspace, while the algebraic multiplicity is $1$. Seems to work here.

Comment: @conditionalMethod But I suppose that matrix over R has no eigenvalue. 1+i is the eigenvalue if that matrix is over C.

Comment: @Bungo I assume that you are talking about $A=P^{-1}DP$. Anyway, that does not seem to help

Comment: @Reveillark Following your reasoning, to prove that $A$ not diagonal, we have to show there's no invertible $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is diagonal. I guess this is too cumbersome

Comment: @Macrophage No, $AP = PD$ is the eigenvalue-eigenvector equation, where the diagonal elements of $D$ are the eigenvalues, and the columns of $P$ are the eigenvectors. This is equivalent to $A = PDP^{-1}$, not $A = P^{-1}DP$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $A$ has no eigenvalues. If it were diagonalizable, then $A = PDP^{-1}$ with a diagonal matrix $D$. This implies $AP = PD$. Let $e_1 = (1,0,0,...,0)^T$ and put $v = Pe_1$. Then
$$
Av = APe_1 = PDe_1 = P(d_1e_1) = d_1Pe_1 = d_1v
$$
with $d_1$ being the first entry of $D$ on the diagonal. Hence, $A$ has the eigenvalue $d_1$, contrary to the assumption.

Comment: Good. This makes sense! Thank you for this. :)

Comment: If you are content with my answer, please check it.

Answer (score 2):

Let me elaborate on my comment:

Assume $A$ where diagonalizable, say $A=PDP^{-1}$ with $D$ diagonal (and real). Any element of the diagonal of $D$ will be a real eigenvalue of $D$. Now, the matrices $A$ and $D$ have the same characteristic polynomial, and thus the same eigenvalues.

Comment: May i ask why they have the same characteristic polynomial?

Comment: @Macrophage Note that $\det(xI-A)=\det(P(xI)P^{-1}-PDP^{-1})=\det(P(xI-D)P^{-1})=\det(D)\det(xI-D)\det(P^{-1})=\det(xI-D)$.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand your argument.